# Jlabel change color on mouse click Java

Tags: java, swing, jlabel

I am adding multiple Jlabel using for loop. What I want is on mouse click, the color of the selected `JLabel` should change and set to the default color on click of another`JLabel`.

[image: enter code here]

Comment: You should add your code

Comment: Conceptually, the idea is simple, but you're going to want to provide some more details about what you have attempted and why it failed - I'm also wondering if a `JList` might be a better choice

Comment: i have used mouseClick event but it sets color of every selection

Comment: Yes, I would imagine it does, did you keep a reference of the last label that was changed and reset it's state?  Of course you could simply provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and we could stop playing a million quick questions

Comment: i have added a pic

Comment: @VinayakPrabhu Annnd, imgur is having issue (at least where I am) so we can't see it ... a runnable example we can copy and paste into our IDE and run (and experiment with and do text searches) would be infinitely better

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you changed the state of the label, you need someway to change it back.  The simplest solution is to maintain a reference to the last label that was changed and when the new label is clicked, reset it's state

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.MouseAdapter;
import java.awt.event.MouseEvent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Test();
    }

    public Test() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            HighlightMouseListener hml = new HighlightMouseListener();
            for (int index = 0; index < 10; index++) {
                JLabel label = new JLabel("Hello " + index);
                label.addMouseListener(hml);
                add(label, gbc);
            }
        }

    }

    public class HighlightMouseListener extends MouseAdapter {
        private JLabel previous;

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Component source = e.getComponent();
            if (!(source instanceof JLabel)) {
                return;
            }
            JLabel label = (JLabel) source;
            if (previous != null) {
                previous.setBackground(null);
                previous.setForeground(null);
                previous.setOpaque(false);
            }
            previous = label;
            label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
            label.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            label.setOpaque(true);
        }

    }

}
```

I still wonder if a [`JList`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/list.html) would be a better and simpler solution, but since I don't know what you're doing, it's all I can do

Comment: I've been meaning to ask you about a different problem altogether, because I think you might be the only one that is active and that can solve my problem. I'm doing an application for my own self learning and I want to upload an image file from my Java application to my localhost xampp server. With my application, I successfully select the image I want to upload with JFileChooser, and display the file in a JLabel, but at the same time I want to upload the same file to a location specified by me in my xampp server and store the file location in my database.

Comment: Now, I've been looking at uploading files to an FTP server but I don't know if that is needed for what I want to do, but I was hoping I could get your opinion on it :)

Comment: That's a broad topic, you could just `post` or `put` the image to the server, assuming you have a means for the server to respond to those requests